# 'int' object has no attribute 'collidepoint'

Tags: python, rect

I am making a simple tic-tac-toe game with pygame. I make a function so when user mouse click a box, it detects and return which box is clicked, I tried to use the collidepoint it it has the 'int' object has no attribute 'collidepoint' error.

This is how I create the gird:

```
def define_boundary(surface, gridData):
    gridBox = grid
    for (x, y) in gridBox:
        currentGrid = pygame.Rect(x * 100, y * 100, 100, 100)
        gridBox[(x, y)] = currentGrid
   print("the boxes are " + str(gridBox))
   return (gridBox)
```

So gridBox is a dictionary of Rect object
Then I write a function for detecting collision, it will be called if there is a mouse click:

```
def check_collide(gridBox):
    point = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for (x, y) in gridBox:
        collide = gridBox[(x, y)].collidepoint(point)
        if collide:
            print(x, y)
            return (x, y)
```

Then the error occurs. I tried to change gridBox[(x, y)].collidepoint(point) into gridBox[(x, y)].rect.collidepoint(point), but it still doesn't work

Comment: It appears as if `gridBox` is not quite what you expect it to be. I am 90% sure the problem is not in this code. I would suggest tracking via `print` or a debugger the value of `gridBox` at everypoint in the application

Comment: The code seems fine. What are you passing as `gridBox` when you call the `check_collide` function?